# Start application in background on bootup

Tags: android

I would like to start my application when the phone boots up. But the user should not know that the application has started. I am doing the boot up by receiving the BOOT_COMPLETE event in a broadcast receiver and am able to minimize the application by using moveTaskToBack(true).
But my application is visible for a split second before it gets minimized and I do not want this to happen. My application does not have any services. Is there any way in which I can start the application minimized without the end user noticing ?

Thanks

Comment: best way for keep execution in background is service so its better to use service instead of activity in background

Comment: My application has a UI which has to be seen, but only when user manually launches it from the home screen. Otherwise it has to be in the background. I understand service is necessary and thats the reason I specifically mentioned I'm not using any. As I said, it could be done but have to remove that split second visibility. Any other ideas you've got ?

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);  
    }
```

}

Comment: wow, this is something new for me. are you sure this will work out without being root?